# Bind notifies on DNS views

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, bind

I have configured two Cent OS based DNS servers one for master and one for slave with internal and external views for a domain. The problem is that i get notifies and automatic zone updates when i perform a reload on the master only for the internal view and not the external.

Any help ?

Am i missing something ?

Thank you

options file of master:

```
    options {

    directory "/var/named";

    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; master; };

    version "None of your business"; 
    server-id "None of your business";
    hostname "None of your business";
    blackhole {badips;};
    auth-nxdomain no;

    transfers-in 3;
    transfers-per-ns 3;
    transfers-out 9;

    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion {127.0.0.1; internals;};

    allow-query {any;};

    allow-transfer {127.0.0.1; slave;};

    max-transfer-time-in 60;

    rate-limit {

        responses-per-second 3;
        window 5;
        log-only yes;
        exempt-clients {mail-ad; slave; };

    };
};
```

options file of slave:

```
    options {

    directory "/var/named";

    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; slave; };

    version "None of your business"; 
    server-id "None of your business";
    hostname "None of your business";
    blackhole {badips;};
    auth-nxdomain no;

    transfers-in 3;
    transfers-per-ns 3;
    transfers-out 9;

    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion {127.0.0.1; internals;};

    allow-transfer {127.0.0.1; master;};

    max-transfer-time-in 60;

    allow-query {any;};

    rate-limit {

        responses-per-second 3;
        window 5;
        log-only yes;
        exempt-clients {mail-ad; master; };

    };
};
```

view of the master:

```
    view domain.com-external {

    match-clients {external;};

    zone "domain.com." IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/named/db.domain.com.external.hosts";
        notify yes;
        also-notify {slave;};
    };

};

view domain.com-internal {

    match-clients {internals;};

    zone "domain.com." IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/named/db.domain.com.internal.hosts";
        notify yes;
    };

    zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "/etc/named/db.root";

    };

    zone "localhost" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/named/db.local";

    };

    zone "127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/named/db.127";

    };

    zone "0.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/named/db.0";

    };

    zone "255.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/named/db.255";

    };

    zone "10.in-addr.arpa"      { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "16.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "17.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "18.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "19.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "20.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "21.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "22.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "23.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "24.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "25.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "26.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "27.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "28.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "29.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "30.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "31.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "168.192.in-addr.arpa" { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };


};
```

views of the slave:

```
v

iew domain.com-external {

    match-clients {external;};

    zone "domain.com." IN {
        type slave;
        masters {master;};
        file "slaves/db.domain.com.external.hosts";
        notify yes;
    };

};

view domain.com-internal {

    match-clients {internals;};

    zone "domain.com." IN {
        type slave;
        masters {masters;};
        file "slaves/db.domain.com.internal.hosts";
        notify yes;

    };

    zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "/etc/named/db.root";

    };

    zone "localhost" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/named/db.local";

    };

    zone "127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/named/db.127";

    };

    zone "0.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/named/db.0";

    };

    zone "255.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/named/db.255";

    };

    zone "10.in-addr.arpa"      { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "16.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "17.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "18.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "19.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "20.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "21.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "22.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "23.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "24.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "25.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "26.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "27.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "28.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "29.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "30.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "31.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };
    zone "168.192.in-addr.arpa" { type master; file "/etc/named/db.empty"; };


};
```

Comment: the server is not in production yet. it is closed by firewall. external zone file contains all the external ips and internal contains the same hostnames with their internal ips

Comment: What does it say in the Bind logs on the server which should be sending the notifications?

Comment: Along the A, AAAA, MX, SOA records, what NS records does the external-facing zone contain?

Comment: logs of the master say that notify is sent. Slave does not receive anything for the external zone.

Comment: it contains A record of  ns1.domain,com pointing to the internal ip address. this is for both zones internal and external.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong?

Comment: Does this happen when you manually flush the cache on the secondary DNS? ```sudo rndc flush```
Can you do a zone transfer manually?
```dig axfr @master.dns dns.domain```